# Expression in Haskell Constructor

Tags: function, haskell, types, constructor, expression

I have to create a function that takes an expression as an argument, like sin 2.5 or cos 1. Is there a constructor type like `Function` or `Expression`?

My teacher gave us a worksheet where he wrote down that this EXISTS, but not how to use it...

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you say what you want it to look like?

Comment: `sin 2.5` is not a function; it's an expression constructed *from* a function that evaluates to a numerical value.

Comment: `sin 2.5` is a number, not a function, and so is `cos 1`.

Comment: Now, if you want to take a *string* like `"sin 2.5"` and return something like `Application "sin" "2.5"` (just using strings here for simplicity, instead of further lexing/parsing/evaluating the two components), for an appropriately defined data constructor `Application`, that's another matter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this exists and it is called Template Haskell.

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.6.5: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :m +Language.Haskell.TH
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> :set -XTemplateHaskell
Prelude Language.Haskell.TH> runQ [|sin 2.5|]
AppE (VarE GHC.Float.sin) (LitE (RationalL (5 % 2)))
```